# How to include application/x-www-form-urlencoded HttpHeader in Akka-http 2.4.1?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am using Akka Http 2.4.1 to post a https request to the twitter api.

According to their [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only), I need two httpheaders.  Namely, Authorization and ContentType.

To quote their docs:

*The request must include a Content-Type header with the value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8.*

Here is my code:

```
val authorization = Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials(key, secret))

/*
   This header is removed from the request with the following explanation!
   "Explicitly set HTTP header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;' is ignored, illegal RawHeader"
*/
val contentType = RawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")

Http().singleRequest(
    HttpRequest(
        uri = Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"),
        method = HttpMethods.POST,
        headers = List(authorization, contentType),
        entity = HttpEntity(`text/plain(UTF-8)`, "grant_type=client_credentials"),
        protocol = HttpProtocols.`HTTP/1.1`))
```

How can I include the `Content-Type` header with the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` using Akka-http 2.4.1?

Comment: Content-Type will be set automatically based on the type of entity being included in the request.  In your case you are setting your http entities content type to `text/plain(UTF-8)`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.  Helpful!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think if you change the `entity` value on your `HttpRequest` to `FormData` like so:

```
HttpRequest(
    uri = Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"),
    method = HttpMethods.POST,
    headers = List(authorization),
    entity = FormData("grant_type" -> "client_credentials").toEntity,
    protocol = HttpProtocols.`HTTP/1.1`)
)
```

Then you should get the `Content-Type` to be automatically set for you to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`